# serverless offline start working but internal server error shows up when deployed

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I created a MERN stack app but when I wrapped in in server less docs , i was successfully able to use my REST APIs when started via server less offline start but as soon as i deploy them I get error on my cloud watch log insight:

```
 "MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out",
        "    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:430:30)",
        "    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)",
        "    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)"
```

I have been stuck on this problem for quite a long time and have tried every solution available( one of them was using bcryptjs rather than bcrypt as it was a previous error).

Can anybody suggest a solution

Comment: Do you connect to some mongodb from lambda?

Comment: yes, i am using mongodb and the function will be accessing it.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Is your lambda in VPC? mongodb is managed aws service, or your own custom mongodb install on some ec2 instance?

Comment: I used serverless and don't know that much about vpc. Told ya new to all this

Comment: Serverless deploy does all the work for me